# How to recover a maria db password

Tags: mysql, centos7, mariadb

I am using maria db for long, and now one of my servers had a necessity of being restored, how can i recover the db password

The server is a centos 7 server

Comment: Did you bother to try even a basic google search? https://lmgtfy.com/?q=Mariadb+rest+password

Comment: nope, thanks for the advice

Answer (score -1):

This can be easily solved by following the steps in the article below:

[Reset mysql root password](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-reset-a-mysql-root-password/)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged here. If you feel the need to answer this question, please add the key steps to your answer.